# Can't use Object.entries with array index structure in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having trouble maping through an array, i am using Object.entries to map the data, find below the example of the json structure. here is what i have tried but i get errors, i know the bath is not correct.

```
{
  Object.entries(this.props.optionData.steps).map((t, k) => (
    <option onClick={(e) => this.optionSelectHandle(t, k)} key={k} value={t[0]}>
      {t[1]}
    </option>
  ));
}


{
    "steps": [{
            "step_num": 1,
            "description": "Description"
        },
        {
            "step_num": 2,
            "description": "Description",
            "uncommon_field": "some data"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Why entries when its  an array?

Comment: Object.entries is only for objects. It returns an array you can map over. However, when you've already got an array, you can simply map over it immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could simply use the map function on steps like such:

```
{
  this.props.optionData.steps.map(step => (
    <option onClick={(e) => this.optionSelectHandle(e)} key={step.step_num} value={step.step_num}>
      {step.description}
    </option>
  ));
}
```

as it is already an array